# Help understanding statement relating to structure of modules over PIDs

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

Lemma IV.6.11 of Hungerford's *Algebra* is

> **Lemma 6.11.** Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain. If $r \in R$ factors as $r = p_1^{n_1} \cdots p_k^{n_k}$ with $p_1,\ldots,p_k \in R$ distinct primes and each $n_i > 0$, then there is an $R$-module isomorphism
>
> $$R/(r) \cong R/(p_1^{n_1}) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(p_k^{n_k}).$$
>
> Consequently every cyclic $R$-module of order $r$ is a direct sum of $k$ cyclic $R$-modules of orders $p_1^{n_1},\ldots,p_k^{n_k}$ respectively.

In his sketch of a proof for Lemma IV.6.11, he says

> The last statement of the lemma is an immediate consequence of the fact that $R/(c)$ is a cyclic $R$-module of order $c$ for each $c \in R$ by Theorem 6.4.

Theorem IV.6.4 goes

> **Theorem 6.4.** Let $A$ be a left module over an integral domain $R$ and for each $a \in A$ let $\mathcal{O}_a = \{r \in R \mid ra = 0\}$.
>
> (i) $\mathcal{O}_a$ is an ideal of $R$ for each $a \in A$.
>
> (ii) $A_t = \{a \in A \mid \mathcal{O}_a \ne 0\}$ is a submodule of $A$.
>
> (iii) For each $a \in A$ there is an isomorphism of left modules
>         $$R/\mathcal{O}_a \cong Ra = \{ra \mid r \in R\}.$$
>
> Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and $p \in R$ a prime.
>
> (iv) If $p^i a = 0$ (equivalently $(p^i) \subset \mathcal{O}_a$), then $\mathcal{O}_a = (p^j)$ with $0 \le j \le i$.
>
> (v) If $\mathcal{O_a} = (p^i)$, then $p^j a \ne 0$ for all $j$ such that $0 \le j < i$.

I don't see how Theorem IV.6.4 implies that $R/(c)$ is a cyclic $R$-module of order $c$ for each $c \in R$. Couldn't there be a principal ideal domain $R$ and $c \in R$ such that for every $R$-module $A$, there is no $a \in A$ having $\mathcal{O}_a = (c)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Couldn't there be a principal ideal domain $R$ and $c \in R$ such that for every $R$-module $A$, there is no $a \in A$ having $\mathcal{O}_a = (c)$?

No, because $A:=R/(c)$ is cyclic (generated by $\bar{1}$) and ${\cal O}_{\bar{1}}=(c)$. Check for yourself! (A scalar element $r\in R$ annihilates $1+(c)$ in $R/(c)$ means that .... [write stuff down, profit]).